# RSSelectionMenu dismiss popup window

Tags: swift

I am using `RSSelectionMenu` as an alert to show a list of dates.

But the window will only dismiss when something is selected.

How can I dismiss the popup with either a Done button or by clicking outside the window.

this is the code I am using for the window from the `Github site`.

```
// or specify alert button title
selectionMenu.show(style: .alert(title: "Select", action: "Done", height: nil), from: self)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please share the GitHub link so that we can check which library you are using?

Comment: When working with a third party library, the first place to look is the `Issues` tab of the repo. This might help https://github.com/rushisangani/RSSelectionMenu/issues/77